# Common function / stored procedures and incompatible updates

Tags: sql, procedure

We have a number of modules within a larger suite that all use a common set of stored procedures and functions, due largely in part to the fact that they all use a common set of data and tables. This approach ensures that all modules receive the same answers for when making the same calls - a very good thing (especially in the financial industry)

However, the downside of this approach is that when we update one module in the suite that requires a change to one of the shared stored procedures or functions it requires that we update almost the entire suite. Which is a bad thing due to time and cost.

What kind of strategies can be employed to mitigate this suite upgrade issue every time we update a single stored procedure, while minimizing the management complexity.

This is similar somewhat to the version issue that Microsoft had with DLL(s) / API(s) where you would see a signature change on an API that would necessitate a xxx2 version, which is not ideal cause then you have basically two versions which both need to be maintained and upgraded with the potential that they get out of synch (i.e. two different answers for the same question).

Any strategies or best practices in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Whatty

Answer (score 0):

Two strategies are views and stored procedures.

Use views to access the data in the tables.  This way, you can change the underlying tables (for one module) and not have to change other modules immediately.  Eventually, you can get around to changing that module as well.  For instance, you might split one table into two different tables for one module.  Other modules will never notice, because they access a view, and you just modify the view to return the original data.

Along these lines, you never want to use `select *`, because the columns, their names, or their ordering might change.

The second strategy is to wrap all `insert`, `update`, and `delete` into stored procedures.  This has a second advantage that you can do checking, logging, and notifications in the procedure.  You can try to mimic this with triggers and constraints, but I find the stored procedure approach much more maintainable.